# Why am I getting a missing return at end of function in this code?

Tags: go

```
func getKeyNameFromDeploymentAndSubnet(subnetType SubnetType, deploymentType DeploymentType, keyNameMap map[SubnetType]string) string {
    if (deploymentType == NoDeployment || deploymentType == PDBAWindows || deploymentType == AgentDeployment) {
        return keyNameMap[subnetType]
    }
    else if (deploymentType == AnsibleDeployment) {
        return "bar"
    }
    return "foo"
}
```

In the first `if` statement, I get an error of missing return at end of function error. I don't get this error if I remove the `else if` statement. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should always use gofmt. It would have solved this issue.

Comment: Neither of the current answers really explain _why_ that error occurs with the `else` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because `else` statement must be on the same line as the closing `}` of the first condition.

```
func getKeyNameFromDeploymentAndSubnet(subnetType SubnetType, deploymentType DeploymentType, keyNameMap map[SubnetType]string) string {
    if deploymentType == NoDeployment || deploymentType == PDBAWindows || deploymentType == AgentDeployment {
        return keyNameMap[subnetType]
    } else if deploymentType == AnsibleDeployment {
        return "bar"
    }
    return "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a return statement in your first `if`, you may just drop the `else` statement. The second `if` is not going to be reached anyway if the first ones conditions are met.

```
func getKeyNameFromDeploymentAndSubnet(subnetType SubnetType, deploymentType DeploymentType, keyNameMap map[SubnetType]string) string {
    if (deploymentType == NoDeployment || deploymentType == PDBAWindows || deploymentType == AgentDeployment) {
        return keyNameMap[subnetType]
    }
    if (deploymentType == AnsibleDeployment) {
        return "bar"
    }
    return "foo"
}
```