# Why am I getting a missing return at the end of function in a for loop

Tags: go

The code looks like:

```
func Contain(livesJSON []LiveJSON, single db.Live) bool {
    for _, json := range livesJSON {
        if json.Start == single.Time && json.Team == single.HomeTeamId {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I have `return` in both `if` and `else`.

Comment: I'm no `go` expert, but generally speaking, if the loop never runs, therefore you don't return anything.

Comment: Is there any point to looping? Based on your conditional, you are going to return on the first iteration if you do enter the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a missing return at end of function in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071362/why-am-i-getting-a-missing-return-at-end-of-function-in-this-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no guarantee the loop body will be executed. This is the case if you pass `nil` or an empty slice for `livesJSON`. That way you would not return anything.

For that case, you must insert a `return` statement after the loop:

```
func Contain(livesJSON []LiveJSON, single db.Live) bool {
    for _, json := range livesJSON {
        if json.Start == single.Time && json.Team == single.HomeTeamId {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```